# zlib gzip decompression python

Tags: php, python, bash, gzip, zlib

my question is possible to extract a compressed files **(gzip deflate) http compression**  with php or python or bash ?

i test this

```
import zlib

str_object1 = open('test.png', 'rb').read()
str_object2 = zlib.decompress(str_object1)
f = open('my_recovered_log_file', 'wb')
f.write(str_object2)
f.close()
```

and a get this result

```
File "testgz", line 4, in <module>
    str_object2 = zlib.decompress(str_object1)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

ty

Comment: png files don't use gzip compression. They use a different compression algorithm. I don't see any indication in your example code of HTTP being used. Perhaps the [png](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html) module is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Pi Marillion is not my website I downloaded a file and it is compressed And I wonder if it is possible to unwind and which information I have to find. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

Although zlib uses the same mechanisms to compress/decompress as gzip, they use different headers as their checksums.

Python's zlib can uncompress gzipped files, but Python provides a convenience library [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The PNG file format has embedded in it one or more zlib streams.  You would need to decode the format in order to find them, at which point you could use `zlib.decompress` to decompress them.  You cannot use zlib to decompress a .png file from the start.

See the [PNG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) for the format.

Your question seems confused, since you give an example of trying to decode a .png file, but you ask about "(gzip deflate) http compression", which is an entirely different thing.  Yes, you can use `zlib.decompress` on those, with the proper usage of the `wbits` parameter.